# Python Pandas - KeyError on pd.merge even when same columns exist across dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to join two dataframes on multiple columns. Even if all the columns exist in both the dataframes, I am getting a key error while doing a pd.merge.

When I am trying to do a .join, then I am getting 
**`"ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right""`**

**Dataframe 1:**

```
>>data.columns
Index(['weather.description', 'weather.icon', 'weather.id', 'weather.main',
       'dt', 'main.pressure', 'main.temp_min', 'main.temp_max', 'main.temp',
       'main.humidity', 'main.grnd_level', 'main.sea_level', 'wind.speed',
       'wind.deg', 'wind.gust', 'id', 'day', 'month', 'hour', 'dd', 'year'],
      dtype='object')

>>data.dtypes
weather.description     object
weather.icon            object
weather.id               int64
weather.main            object
dt                      object
main.pressure          float64
main.temp_min          float64
main.temp_max          float64
main.temp              float64
main.humidity            int32
main.grnd_level        float64
main.sea_level         float64
wind.speed             float64
wind.deg               float64
wind.gust              float64
id                     float64
day                     object
month                   object
year                    object
hour                    object
dd                      object
dtype: object
```

**Dataframe 2:**

```
>>df_crime.columns
Index(['beat', 'disposition', 'event_date', 'event_number', 'general_location',
       'location_1', 'map_x', 'map_y', 'type', 'type_description', 'ward',
       'day', 'year', 'month', 'dd', 'hour'],
      dtype='object')

>>df_crime.dtypes
beat                 object
disposition          object
event_date           object
event_number         object
general_location     object
location_1           object
map_x               float64
map_y               float64
type                 object
type_description     object
ward                float64
day                  object
year                 object
month                object
dd                   object
hour                 object
dtype: object
```

**Inner Join Query:**

```
result = pd.merge(data,
                  df_crime[['type_description']],
                  on=['year','month','dd','hour']
                  )
```

**Error:**

```
KeyError: 'year'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the `'year','month','dd','hour'` column in the merge:

You are missing out on other columns, when you are taking just `df_crime[['type_description']]` in the merge.

Your `on` has 4 columns and all should be present in the slice of the dataframe you are taking inside `pd.merge()`

Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) , where you can use the `suffixes=` method to differentiate between the common columns(FYI)

Comment: Adding the join columns in the dataframe column selection worked! Thanks. However, didn't understand how will suffix be helpful in this case?

Comment: `suffix=` by default is `_x` and `_y` where `_x` is for the left dataframe and `_y` is for the right dataframe, this wont be helpful for this case, but in general if you want you could rename it. :)